# Solving $z^3 =-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find the solution of $z^{3} =-1$.
Let$$z=[ r,\theta ]$$
then using de Moivre's theorm$$ z^{3} =\left[ r^{3} ,3\theta \right] $$
write the number $-1$ in modulus argument from,
$$[ 1,( 2n-1) \pi ]$$
the we can write$$\left[ r^{3} ,3\theta \right] =[ 1,( 2n-1) \pi ]$$
Therefore,$$ r^{3} =1 \space \text{and} \space \theta =\frac{( 2n-1) \pi }{3}$$
Then$$z_{n} =1\left( \cos\frac{( 2n-1) \pi }{3} +i\sin\frac{( 2n-1) \pi }{3}\right)$$
\begin{align}
&n=0 \quad z_{0} =\frac{1}{2} -i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&n=1 \quad z_{1} =\frac{1}{2} +i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&n=2 \quad z_{1} =-1\\
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is correct. You can see this from: Your three solutions are clearly solutions and distinct. As this *can* only have three distinct solutions, these are all solutions.

Comment: "*write the number −1 in modulus argument from ...*" $\;-\;$ Except the modulus must be a non-negative number, and the argument is *not* $\,n \pi\,$.

Comment: @Lazy No, the answer is not correct. The first red flag is that the complex roots should be conjugates, while OP's are not.

Comment: You have mentioned complex root of unity, but then solved z^3=-1. If you want the complex roots of unity, shouldn't it be z^3=1.

Comment: I'm following the lecture note, It has not any examples. It noted that Complex root of unity. @Starlight I'm sorry, I don't know much about that.

Comment: @dxiv Oh yeah, I didn’t read closely enough to spot that there is a big modulus error (that’s what being tired does for you). Basically the error is that you do not want $(-1,n\pi)$ but $(-1,n2\pi)$, as $e^{it}$ is $2\pi$-periodic. So then $\theta = 2n\pi/3$.

Comment: @dxiv, thanks sir

Comment: Note that unity means 1,  not (-1).

Comment: @Lazy now is it correct? updated

Comment: @Lazy The canonical modulus-argument representation is $\,\big(1, (2n+1)\pi\big)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I think it is correct now. Thank you sir

Comment: @dxiv That is correct, but irrelevant for the construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=re^{i\theta}$

$z^3 = -1$

$r^3 (e^{3 i \theta})= 1\cdot e^{i\pi}$

Hence, $  r=1$ and $\theta= \frac{i(\pi + 2k\pi) }{3}$ for $k=0, 1,2$

$z= e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}} , e^{i\pi}, e^{\frac{5i\pi}{3}}$

Answer (score 2):

You can find the complex roots of unity as below. The equation you have solved is *not* the one that will give you complex roots of unity.

$$z^3=1 \implies z^3-1=0$$
Factor the LHS (using any of a variety of methods):
$$(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0$$
Use the zero-product property:
$$z-1=0\implies z=1$$
$$z^2+z+1=0\implies z=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
(where we used the quadratic formula above)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But I need to solve above equation by using complex complex number de moivre's theorem.